# Making a module that creates a stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to add rules to css with js and I came across this line of code. I can't figure out how this return works and how can I possibly rewrite it in my own project.

```
var sheet = function() {    
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    document.head.appendChild(style);   
    return style.sheet;
}();
```

Ideally I want to wrap it in some module such as

```
var AddCssStyles = {
    makeSheet: function(){
        this.stylesheet = document.CreateElement...
        // return a stylesheet for later use
    }
}
var navigationHeight = Object.create(AddCssStyles);
navigationHeight.makeSheet();
```

Which would let me access the sheet with navigationHeight.stylesheet to make the changes.

Comment: Would styles apply to entire document , or specific elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how this return works

That code creates a function and then calls it immediately, throwing away the function. That's what the `()` near the end do (call the function). So the result is that the code in the function is run, creating the `style` element, and the `sheet` property of the resulting `style` element is returned, and then kept as the `sheet` variable.

> and how can I possibly rewrite it in my own project.
>
> Ideally I want to wrap it in some module such as

You're on the right track, a couple of tweaks (see comments):

```
var AddCssStyles = {
    makeSheet: function(){
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        document.head.appendChild(style);   
        this.stylesheet =  style.sheet;
        return this.stylesheet;
    }
}
var navigationHeight = Object.create(AddCssStyles);
var sheet = navigationHeight.makeSheet();
```

...then use `sheet` to add rules. Or add a method to your object prototype that defines rules on `this.stylesheet`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, its all clear now, although I feel silly for not being able to come up with a solution myself.